# ASP.NET Menu control adds a <style> tag for every Menu control on the page. How can I group or delete these style tags?

Tags: html, asp.net, menu, styles

I have an ASP.net page that adds menu controls dynamically, about 50. .NET adds a style tag for each menu control. The problem is that IE8 reads only the first 25 style tags and ignores the rest. I think that the solution will be to group all style tags into one or remove all style tags. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The style tags from the page source:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */
#ctl08 img.icon { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
#ctl08 img.separator { border-style:none;display:block; }
#ctl08 ul { list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:auto; }
#ctl08 ul.dynamic { z-index:1; }
#ctl08 a { text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;display:block; }
#ctl08 a.dynamic.highlighted { font-weight:bold; }
/* ]]> */
</style><style type="text/css"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */
#ctl09 img.icon { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
#ctl09 img.separator { border-style:none;display:block; }
#ctl09 ul { list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:auto; }
#ctl09 ul.dynamic { z-index:1; }
#ctl09 a { text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;display:block; }
#ctl09 a.dynamic.highlighted { font-weight:bold; }
/* ]]> */
</style><style type="text/css"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */
#ctl10 img.icon { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
#ctl10 img.separator { border-style:none;display:block; }
#ctl10 ul { list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:auto; }
#ctl10 ul.dynamic { z-index:1; }
#ctl10 a { text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;display:block; }
#ctl10 a.dynamic.highlighted { font-weight:bold; }
/* ]]> */
</style><style type="text/css"> 
...
```

Comment: Are you open to jQuery based solutions?

Comment: Perhaps instead of let menu generate its own style, specify your own CSS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731(v=vs.100).aspx